# django-uploadify http error 500 after upload

Tags: django, http, uploadify

### Used technologies

- [django-uploadify](https://github.com/tstone/django-uploadify) (multiple file upload)
- Django 1.3 testing web server

### Context

I can upload successfully files to the web server using the upload.html page (the upload directory has the required permissions). However, when the upload is completed, the web server returns a HTTP 500 error.

```
"POST /filemanager/view HTTP/1.1" 500 68788
```

The */filemanager/view* page render correctly if I access it directly (GET).

### Code

**filemanager/urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = patterns('filemanager.views',
    url(r'^upload/', direct_to_template, {'template': 'upload.html'}),
    url(r'^view/',
        ListView.as_view(
            queryset = Container.objects.all(),
            context_object_name='containers',
            template_name='view.html'),
        name='view'
        )
)
```

**filemanager/templates/upload.html**

```html
{% load uploadify_tags %}
{% load url from future %}

<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/js/uploadify/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/js/uploadify/swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/js/uploadify/jquery.uploadify.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        {% multi_file_upload '/filemanager/view' %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**filemanager/templates/view.html**

```html
<html>
    <h1>File list</h1>
    <ul>
    {% if containers %}
        {% for container in containers %}
            <li>{{ container.file }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    </ul>
</html>
```

Is it possible that the Django testing web server is buggy while performing this type of operation? Suggestions?

Comment: you can add DEBUG = True in your settings.py file and you will be able to see a full stacktrace.

Comment: The variable is already set to True but I can't see the stacktrace. It just stays on the upload page.